# Make element align to absolute positioned element as if it was relative

Tags: html, css

I want to create responsive popup banner with close button here is my simple scenario:

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="...">
    <a href="" class="close-btn">X</a>
</div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.banner img{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
.close-btn{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    z-index:2;
    color:red;
    background:#000;
    padding:4px;
}
```

As you can see I stretch image depending on width and height.

**Problem**: I want `close-btn` to stick to the right side of the image and overlap it. To solve this the `banner` must be the same width as the image. If `banner` has `position:absolute` its width and height of course is 0.

Is it possible to achieve only with CSS?

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fjckls/qq590xz5/

I need image to be responsive to **width and height**

[image: I need image to be responsive to **width and height**]

Comment: This sounds possible, but could you possibly create a mockup image in paint? Just so this is clear what you're looking to do. Alternatively, would it be possible to use a background image on a div instead of an image tag itself?

Comment: Alternatively, you could remove the img ' s absolute property, and have the banner div set to position:relative. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/qq590xz5/4/)

Comment: @jbutler483 I need image to be responsive to width and height. In your case it only resizes to width, not height...

Comment: [don't use percentage units then...](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/qq590xz5/6/)

Comment: @jbutler483 thats pretty cool -  CSS3 FTW! Please write it as answer and I will accept it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your image fully width AND height responsive, first off, you need to alter your units. You're currently using `%`'s which is all well and good, but for the 'fully height responsive' concept, the % units aren't much help.

Instead, you should look into using `vh` (view-height) and `vw` (view-width) units, since these are for the **actual viewport** that the user can see currently.

---

In order to position your 'x' over the top right of your image, you're going to have to alter your css slightly.

You could possibly include a css rule for your banner, first off. Something like:

```
.banner {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Whilst removing the 'position:absolute' rule from your image, since now your banner div will be the size of your image (not the default '100% of screen' that divs are set to originally).

---

This leaves us one problem, you haven't actually set where abouts you want the 'x' to appear vertically, so it will default to 'where it would position normally', which, in this case, would be below the image. To tackle this, you would need to add a `top:` or `bottom:` declaration to your 'x' class, and in my case, i've chosen to set it to the top (`top:0;`).

The overall fiddle can be shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/qq590xz5/6/)

or here:

```css
.banner img {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: red;
  background: #000;
  padding: 4px;
}
.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="http://sockets.hogwartsishere.com/media/book_covers/l-bunny.jpg" /> <a href="" class="close-btn">X</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, with this I avoided using javascript! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the link

http://jsfiddle.net/qq590xz5/3/

```
<div class="banner">
    <div style="position:abolute;">
    <img src="http://sockets.hogwartsishere.com/media/book_covers/l-bunny.jpg">
     <a href="" class="close-btn">X</a>
        </div>
</div>

.banner img{
    max-width:50%;
    max-height:100%;

}
.close-btn{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    color:red;
    top:1%;
    background:#000;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Have a look

Thanks

Comment: No, this doesn't work as its not responsive - I need image to be responsive to height and width

Comment: .banner img{
    max-width:100%;
    
 
}  this makes the image responsive

Comment: in that case you will need to set as background image and set image size as cover

Answer (score 0):

try this..

**Html**

```
<div class="banner">
    <img src="http://sockets.hogwartsishere.com/media/book_covers/l-bunny.jpg">
     <a href="" class="close-btn">X</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
}

img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.close-btn{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    color:red;
    background:#000;
    padding:4px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w8zwv3a7/)

Comment: Image is not responsive to width and height

Comment: it is responsive.. try to change the width of the container (.banner) and see the result

Comment: @fjckls, did you try that??

Comment: yes, resize vertically and you'll see that image is not responsive to height

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that keeps the image centered horizontally *and* the x button on the top right of the image. It involves:

1) Making the `.banner` absolutely positioned, with margins from each window edge. This centers the entire .banner, however you might want to use fixed position if you need it to scroll along with the user's viewport.

It'll work as long as there aren't any other positioned elements as its parents.

```
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  bottom: 5%;
}
```

2) Making a thing that sticks around the image, which will serve as a positioning guide for the little X.

```
 <div class="shrinkwrap">
     <img src="...">
     <a href="" class="close-btn">X</a>
 </div>

.shrinkwrap { 
  /* shrink-wraps this div around its content;
     as a side-effect, lets this div be centered with text-align: center; */
  display: inline-block; 

  /* new positioning context! */
  position: relative; 

  /* keeps the responsiveness */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
```

3) Positioning the shrinkwrapper to always be in the center of the `.banner`.

```
.banner {
  /* ... */ 
  text-align: center;
}

.close-btn {
  /* ... */
  top: 0;  
}
```

The finished version of this is here: http://jsfiddle.net/boxmein/qq590xz5/5/

Comment: Close button doesn't stick to the corner of the image, but to the corner of the wrapper..

Comment: But since the wrapper sticks to the image, then it's also the corner of the image. :)

Comment: Resize vertically and you'll see the problem - X sticks to the wrapper - while image downscales.